# Django - ModelForm: Add a field not belonging to the model

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-crispy-forms

Note: Using `django-crispy-forms` library for my form. If you have a solution to my problem that involves not using the `cripsy_forms` library, I accept it all the same. Not trying to be picky just need a solution / work around. Thanks

In my form's `Meta` class I set the model, `Driftwood`, and it's fields I want to in the form, but I also want to add another field. One that does not belong the the referenced model. This field I want to add is an image. The reason for this field is to build another model from it.

I have a model named `Image` that has some fields that get populated by doing things with a single `models.ImageField()`. This `Image` also has a `models.ForeginKey()` with a relation to the `Driftwood` model. So `Image` can be accessed through an instance of a `Driftwood` using its relational set property (`driftwood.image_set`).

In `view.py` I am using `generic.CreateView()` as the inherited class that will handle my form class. I plan on using the `form_valid()` method to acquire through `form.cleaned_data`, the image that I need. I will then create the image, passing the `object.id` of my newly instantiated `Driftwood` and the image into my `Image` model.

The problem I have though is not knowing how to add a custom field to Django's `FormModel` that does not belong to the model associated with the form.

### forms.py

```
from django import forms

from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper
from crispy_forms.layout import Layout, ButtonHolder, Submit

from . import models

class DriftwoodForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Driftwood
        fields = ('user', 'title', 'description')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(DriftwoodForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            'user',
            'Insert Image Field Here',
            'title',
            'description',
            ButtonHolder(
                Submit('save', 'Save', css_class='btn-success')
            )
        )
```

### models.py

```
from base64 import b64decode, b64encode # used to encode/decode image

from django.db import models

class TimeStampMixin(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)


class Driftwood(TimeStampMixin):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255)


class Image(TimeStampMixin):

    driftwood = models.ForeignKey(Driftwood)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='static/images')

    # gets encoded as a string in the save method
    encoded_image = models.TextField(blank=True, null=False, default='')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how you do it to a non django-crispy-forms form:

```
from django import forms

from . import models


class DriftwoodForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Driftwood
        fields = ('user', 'title', 'description', 'image')

    image = forms.ImageField()
```

full documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ImageField

---

Now what you have to do is simply use the form as you always do, calling `save()` on the form won't try to brute save the image to the model specified in the `Meta` class, but you will be able to do whatever you want with the field.

I'm not sure thou, but i suppose you can do the same with django-crispy-forms, just add the field below and suppose its from the model itself.

Comment: AH, Wonderful. So simple, I love simplicity, where it should be. Thanks for the help. I haven't tweeked to much with crispy_forms yet, but I ll find a way.

Comment: you should definitely read this, it ll make things easier. 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/

Comment: Ok `crispy_forms` is awesome I only needed to replace `'Insert Image Field Here',`to `'image',` in the layout and all works well now.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I've been reading through django docs a lot lately. I fear that I will never finish it.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the updated form in case anyone was curious.

```
class DriftwoodForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Driftwood
        fields = ('user', 'title', 'description', 'image')

    image = forms.ImageField()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(DriftwoodForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            'user',
            'image',
            'title',
            'description',
            ButtonHolder(
                Submit('save', 'Save', css_class='btn-success')
            )
        )
```