# django form.is_valid returns false after adding fields dynamically to the form

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have a form like this,

```
class UniqueUrlForm(forms.ModelForm):
    cc_number = cc_form.CardNumberField(label='Card Number')
    cc_expiry = cc_form.CardExpiryField(label='Expiration Date')
    cc_code = cc_form.SecurityCodeField(label='CVV/CVC')

    class Meta:
        model = Transactions
        fields = ['customer_name', 'customer_phone', 'customer_email', 'total_amount', 'cc_number', 'cc_expiry',
                  'cc_code']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()

        store_id = kwargs.get("store_id", "1")
        payment_page = get_object_or_404(
            PaymentPageDisplayDetails.objects.filter(store_id=store_id).values("payment_fields_visible"))

        with urllib.request.urlopen(payment_page['payment_fields_visible']) as url:
            display_fields = json.loads(url.read().decode())

        for field_name in display_fields:
            self.fields[field_name] = forms.CharField(required=False)
```

and a view like this,

```
def getpaymentpage(request, store_identifier):
    uniqueurl_form = UniqueUrlForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, {"store_id": 1})

    if uniqueurl_form.is_valid():

            trx_details = {
                "amount": uniqueurl_form.cleaned_data['amount'],
                "customer_email": uniqueurl_form.cleaned_data['customer_email'],
                "customer_phone": uniqueurl_form.cleaned_data['customer_phone'],
                "cc_number": uniqueurl_form.cleaned_data['cc_number'],
                "cc_name": uniqueurl_form.cleaned_data['customer_name'],
                "cc_month": uniqueurl_form.cleaned_data['cc_month'],
                "cc_year": uniqueurl_form.cleaned_data['cc_year'],
                "cvv": uniqueurl_form.cleaned_data['cvv'],
            }

        return HttpResponse(trx_details)
    context = {
        'form': {
            uniqueurl_form,
        },
        "page": store_display,
    }
    return render(request, 'unique_url.html', context)
```

I have tried `print(uniqueurl_form.errors)` it always returns empty and uniqueurl_form.is_valid() as false.

Is it because I'm adding dynamic fields to the form.
I have referred the following,

[dynamically add field to a form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6142025/dynamically-add-field-to-a-form)

What am I doing wrong here?
Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: Are you sure your model has all dynamically added fields? Note, in the referred answer there is a Form class, not Modelform

Comment: @VitAmin No Model doesnt have these fields, since I don't want to save them but according to this answer(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30957113/django-modelform-add-a-field-not-belonging-to-the-model) I can add the fields not belonging to model right?

Comment: just use a regular Form class!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

weirdly it started working when i made following changes,

```
class UniqueUrlForm(forms.ModelForm):
    cc_number = cc_form.CardNumberField(label='Card Number')
    cc_expiry = cc_form.CardExpiryField(label='Expiration Date')
    cc_code = cc_form.SecurityCodeField(label='CVV/CVC')

    class Meta:
        model = Transactions
        fields = ['customer_name', 'customer_phone', 'customer_email', 'total_amount', 'cc_number', 'cc_expiry',
                  'cc_code']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        store_id = kwargs.get("store_id", "1")

        super(UniqueUrlForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        payment_page = get_object_or_404(
            PaymentPageDisplayDetails.objects.filter(store_id=store_id).values("payment_fields_visible"))

        with urllib.request.urlopen(payment_page['payment_fields_visible']) as url:
            display_fields = json.loads(url.read().decode())

        for field_name in display_fields:
            self.fields[field_name] = forms.CharField()
```

my guess is because I did not specify class name in my `.super()` event though it was appending the fields it was not sure what validations to put on those fields.